# How restrictions in xsd works on complex type?

Tags: xml, xsd

I've two xsd files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:pt="http://release11.com/PersonType"
           targetNamespace="http://release11.com/LibraryMemberType">
    <xs:import namespace="http://release11.com/PersonType"/>

    <xs:complexType name="LibraryMemberType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="pt:PersonType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                    <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="libraryMember" type="LibraryMemberType" />
</xs:schema>
```

Could you give me some example of valid xml for this xsd? I'm not sure how it should looks

Comment: The shown xsd file is just declaring a complex type `LibraryMemberType` that inherits from base type `PersonType`. The added value of the new complex type is the restriction about the order of elements under the `pt:PersonType`. So, the `id`, `firstName` and `lastName` have to appear in the given order. In order to enable someone give you an example you should share also the content of the other xsd including the declaration of `PersonType`.

Comment: You can check also an online sample xml generator (from xsd) here: http://xsd2xml.com/